# XSD Allow constrained but extendable list of children

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a job-control XML schema I'm trying to develop an XSD for, but XSD appears to be designed for top-down restrictive children selection, and groups can only be added to at declaration, not contributed to by later extension files.

An abbreviated example document follows...

```
<sxtdl xmlns="http://********/xsd/sxtdl" xmlns:map="http://********/xsd/sxtdl/map">
    <reference name="internal" />

    <process id="Tests/SxTDL/Map/Map Initialize">
        Make sure this variable did not previously exist, then
        initialize a map into it and check that it exists.
        <not>
            <expect variable="testmap" />
        </not>
        <map:initialize name="testmap" />
        <expect variable="testmap" />
    </process>
</sxtdl>
```

Notes on the expected schema here:

- The root element `sxtdl` allows any number of "Declaration"s as children. `reference` and `process` are Declarations.
- The `process` Declaration allows any number of "Directives" as children.
- Many Directive elements may take sub-Directives as children, such as the `not` element seen here.
- I need to be able to recognize Directives from extension sources, such as the Key-Value-Map related directives shown in namespace `map:` above.

Ideally what I would like to be able to do is avoid adding `<any/>` into the accepted children of `sxtdl`, `process`, `not`, et cetera, but instead somehow specify something equivalent to `<any namespace="##any" fromGroup="DirectiveGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />`, while somehow appending to DirectiveGroup in those other XSD documents (such as the one for the namespace `.../sxtdl/map`).

The closest I can find to this is substitution groups, but it appears I can only substitute an element for another if the substitution has the same type, just a different tag name... which won't work for Directives that have their own distinct sets of valid attributes.